# windows phone app how to intergrate video player using only c# code

Tags: windows-phone-7

in my application i want to navigate from a page which is extending Canvas to the video player 
for video player page i hav created one class and i m doing this there

```
 MediaElement videoPlayer = new MediaElement();
 videoPlayer.Source = (new Uri("some video url", UriKind.Absolute));
 videoPlayer.AutoPlay = true;
 videoPlayer.Play();
```

but when i m going to that page nothing is happning 
can some body tell me what i m missing.
i am new to windows development.
thanks is advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to insert the MediaElement into your VisualTree. For example, if your canvas' name is `LayoutRoot` (the default), you could to this:

```
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(videoPlayer);
```